# How to use the Zxing barcode scanner library along with the Aforge webcam library

Tags: c#, wpf, barcode, webcam, barcode-scanner

I have a program in which I use the Aforge library for viewing a webcam.
This works wonder:

```
LocalWebcamsCollection = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
LocalScannerBarcode = new VideoCaptureDevice(LocalWebcamsCollection[WebcamNumber].MonikerString);
LocalScannerBarcode.NewFrame += LocalScannerBarcode_NewFrame;
LocalScannerBarcode.Start();
```

and in the new frame event I get the bitmap

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap frame;    
void LocalScannerBarcode_NewFrame(object sender, AForge.Video.NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    frame = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
}
```

now I have to decode what is seen. Basically I have to pass the bitmap to decode.
So global I have;

```
ZXing.BarcodeReader bcr;
```

and into the event LocalScannerBarcode_NewFrame

```
if (bcr == null)
        bcr = new ZXing.BarcodeReader();
```

but as soon as I put the two lines above the event is not called anymore.

Please notice that in Windows forms that works but I have to do it in WPF.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this helps but have you tried putting the reference to the ZXing library in another project? Something an Helper.

So in you project you will have:

```
string strResult = Helper.ReadBarcode(frame);
if (strResult != null)
{
            ... do stuff with the string
}
```

and in the helper

```
static ZXing.BarcodeReader bcr;
public static string ReadBarcode(System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp)
{
    if (bcr == null)
        bcr = new ZXing.BarcodeReader();
    return bcr.Decode(bmp).ToString();
}
```